# Is dequeueAll on mutable.SynchronizedQueue thread-safe?

Tags: scala, concurrency, thread-safety

Looking at the  source code of SynchronizedQueue.scala, it looks like dequeueAll is not overriden  ?   Is this a bug  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean [this dequeueAll](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/SynchronizedQueue.scala#L76)?

```
override def dequeueAll(p: A => Boolean): Seq[A] = synchronized { super.dequeueAll(p) }
```

You can click "blame" on github where the helpful comment shows the ticket. Click it or ticket.

Comment: So this  has been fixed in the master then .. It is not there in v2.9.2 https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/SynchronizedQueue.scala

Comment: So I saw. And it was reported against 2.8.  At least it's not a blocker.